# How to download public file to server?

Tags: shell, command-line, ssh, command, putty

I am trying to download this file via SSH directly to my server:  http://chromium-browser-source.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium.r176602.tgz

What command do I need to use to do this?

All the docs I have seen are just teaching how to connect from one server to another using SSH but I don't need to do that since this file is publicly downloadable of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this :

```
wget http://chromium-browser-source.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium.r176602.tgz
```

or use curl

Comment: That worked perfect!  Thanks!  Do you know the command to unzip .tgz files be chance?

Comment: I tried that actually and got this error: `End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on the last disk(s) of this archive.`